# How to programmatically differentiate between extractive and abstractive summarization in NLP?

Tags: python, nlp, automatic-summarization

We are using different pre-trained models in python transformers library, to generate summaries(both extractive and abstractive). So is there a programmatic way, based on the output summary, we can classify it as abstractive or extractive?

One method I think of is using the rouge python library to compute rouge score with respect to original input text(not human reference summary), which will have rouge(specifically LCS) precision score as 1.0 for extractive(since all the words present in summary will be present in original text). Whereas for abstractive summary some words present in summary will not be in original text and hence precision score will be less than 1.0. Please let me know if this is the right approach? Or is there any other way to differentiate between extractive and abstractive summaries?

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. Fwiw I think it's the right approach, but wouldn't it be much easier and accurate to find this info from the doc of the summarization method instead of predicting it from the output?

Comment: @Erwan Currently we are using transformers library, which has models like Pegasus(CNN DailyMail) which can generate both abstractive and extractive summary and there is no way mentioned in doc's to differentiate between them. It just says both extractive and abstractive summary can be generated. Below is the link which mentions the same https://huggingface.co/datasets/cnn_dailymail

Comment: I think there's a confusion: the doc you link is about the dataset, which can be used to train a summarization model (and probably for other goals as well). Of course the dataset isn't specific to any particular kind of summarization, however a model trained (from this dataset or another one) would have to use a specific summarization method. In particular [Pegasus is clearly described as an abstractive method](https://ai.googleblog.com/2020/06/pegasus-state-of-art-model-for.html), not an extractive one.

Comment: Your idea is ok though, I think using ngrams similarity measures like Rouge or Bleu is a good way to measure the level of  "abstractiveness". It's just that it seems a bit convoluted, it's like trying to guess who a phone number belongs to because we forgot who we were talking to at the time we wrote it down ;)